# Project translation from Java to C#

Tags: discussion, code-length

I have translated a project from Java to C#. I want to have a review of this project as some of the results are not as desired though the code is executing successfully.

How to share this project as it contains much code? Do I need to discuss each and every part of code or via what can I share the code description?

Comment: perhaps get rid of the needless implementation details and focus on the aspects which you want to focus on.

Answer (score 8):

If your code is not working as intended, you should not ask about how to fix it on Code Review. Such a question would be considered off-topic.

Assuming that your code *does* work as intended, you still need to post the code to be reviewed directly in the question. You may optionally add links to external sites (such as GitHub) as a supplement. The size limit is 64 kB.  However, if you have a very large project, it would be a good idea to frame your question to [focus on some portion of the project](/q/1919/9357). Otherwise, the question might be too overwhelming to be appealing or too complex to be reviewed adequately.

Comment: I meant to say that my code is executing successfully, almost working as intended but not to fine grain as e.g. the code is about clustering, whereas it is clustering all the data items in individual clusters for each instance, such type of bugs (technical errors I hope so) are there in code to be reviewed

Comment: @Taufel to be clear: the code is ready to be peer reviewed once it works as intended in all intended use cases; "reviewing code" isn't a bug-hunting exercise - "works as intended" goes further than "compiles and runs".

Comment: @Mat'sMug now its clear to me that a project which compiles and runs successfully doesn't mean that it is as it is intended.

Answer (score 3):

We have a higher characterlimit here on CR, but usually lots of code will scary off answerers so I would suggest you strip your question down to one class or some methods out of this class (if the class is too big).

After you have received hopefully good answers you should incorporate these answers into the remaining code of your project. If you then still aren't satisfied with the remaining code you should come back and ask either a follow up question (targeting the same code) with a link to the previous question or ask a new question involving new code.

Comment: Right but the whole project at once couldn't be reviewed? Am I right?

Comment: The whole project at once *could* be reviewed, just that--citing the answer--*"lots of code will scary off answerers"*. :d

Comment: @zyabin101--What do you mean can whole project be reviewed at once or not ? If yes, then what should be the medium to share the whole project e.g. C# project?

Comment: @Taufel well, reviewing an entire project... the medium to start would be my pay-pal email or bitcoin :-P

Comment: @t3chb0t pay-pal or bitcoin? Hiring?

Comment: @Taufel there's an open-source project with over 100K lines of code being reviewed on this site - browse the [tag:rubberduck] tag to see how a huge project can be broken down into reasonable posts that won't "scary off answerers". Note, if your coding style is any consistent then answers to the first post could apply to the rest of the code base too, so it's best to avoid swarming the site with a dozen questions about various parts of your project all at once. If the whole project fits a single post... heck why not. [This](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2320/23788) is relevant =)